# Full props declaration (with defaults and validators) in Vue 3 + TypeScript + <script setup>

Tags: typescript, validation, vuejs3

So here is a basic example of modern Vue 3 props declaration with `<script setup lang="ts">` with mandatory `name` and optional `age`:

```typescript
// <script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  name: string,
  age?: number
}>()
// </script>
```

Here is the same declaration, but with `age` having default value:

```typescript
// <script setup lang="ts">
withDefaults(defineProps<{
  name: string,
  age?: number
}>(), {
  age: 20
})
// </script>
```

My main question is: **is there a way to incorporate validators in this new syntax**? Or whenever I need to add a validator, I need to roll back to the old syntax, i.e.:

```typescript
// <script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  age: {
    type: Number,
    validator(value: number) => value > 0
  }
})
// </script>
```

I've found similar topics where some suggest to use both generic types and pass parameters to defineProps like this:

```typescript
// <script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  age: number
}>({
  age: {
    validator(value: number) => value > 0
  }
})
// </script>
```

But this approach doesn't work and immediately falls with the error: `defineProps has both a type-only props and an argument.` ([eslintvue/valid-define-props](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/valid-define-props.html))